# Test Signal Detection approach like Energy detection

Tags: detection, energy, probability-theory, performance-estimation

I use natural logarithm or Cepstrum tailored with conventional detection algorithm like energy detection .I want to derive relation between probability of detection and probability of false alarm 
My Question :
Does it possible to vary the amplitude of simulated signal according to different SNR in the applied relation between probability of detection and false alarm .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming question, this doesn't sound like a programming problem, but more one of signal or data analyses.

Comment: Yes , it mix between programming simulation and signal processing